# How to check a url contains particular word in laravel blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to check a particular word example "**myproject**" in the URL,
can check it in the blade file.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to name the routes. Then you can check easily with

```php
if (\Route::is('myproject')) {
   ... route name is myproject
}

// or

if (\Route::current()->getName() === 'myproject') {
   ... route name is myproject
}
```

If you dont name the route you can search in the url string. The url string you can get with:

1. `$request->url()`
2. `url()->current()`
3. `url()->full();`

Then you can check like:

```php
if (str_contains(url()->current(, 'myproject')) {
   // ... url  contains myproject
}
```

Comment: thanks, resolved by adding @if(Request::is('myproject','myproject/*'))

Comment: @AthsalKJ You welcome! If you found this question helpful it would be nice if you accept my answer or upvote. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can like this:

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 $url = url()->full();
 $contains = Str::contains($url, 'myproject');
 // or check two or more word
 $contains = Str::contains($myString, ['myproject', 'secondword']);
 if($contains){
  echo "myproject exists in URL";
 }else{
  echo "myproject is not exists in URL"
 }
```

Comment: thank you, can use this one to check it in PHP.